# Javascript query selector The string did not match the expected pattern

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pass the value of a checkbox *only* if it is checked, I'm using a text input. I'm running into a syntax issue.. I don't see where I missed any brackets or anything. Any help is appreciated. Fiddle is here also

Thanks

```js
document.querySelector(function() {
    setTarget();
    document.querySelector("#test").change(setTarget);
 

    function setTarget() {
         var tmp ="";
        
        tmp += document.querySelector("#test:checked").value || '';
        document.querySelector('#testtarget').val(tmp);
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test123" value="testing123"  />this should appear in the text input<br/>
<input type="text" id="testtarget" name="targetTextField" size="31" tabindex="0" maxlength="99" value="">
```

Comment: You cannot pass a function to `document.querySelector`, it has to be a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector . It's no clear to me what you are trying to achieve by doing that.

Comment: `querySelector` recieves only string as parameter so its a clear syntax error and i cant understand why you have created annonymous function inside `querySelector` ? thats a really bad practice even if it was allowed

Comment: @AmirRahman actually you can pass in anything to querySelector as long as that returns a string, it doesn't matter. 

Though its a bad practice and anti-selection, but just wanted to call to your attention it JavaScript right .

Comment: @Emmanuel Onah i never said you cant pass , i said it `recieves` only string and in code above its a annonymous function inside that selector and also 1 more thing if you resolve anything before passing it into a function its not considered as passing instead its resolving before passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to select checked checkboxes only you can use `:checked` with your querySelector
use it this way

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
```

if i am not wrong this is what you exactly want

```js
var cb = document.querySelector("#test"),
    inp = document.querySelector("#testtarget")
    
cb.onchange = function(e){
   inp.value = cb.checked ? cb.value : ""
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test123" value="testing123"  />this should appear in the text input<br/>
<input type="text" id="testtarget" name="targetTextField" size="31" tabindex="0" maxlength="99" value="">
```

Comment: I see, well in this case I'm trying to target a specific box hence the id, then only if that checkbox is checked, then pass that value to the text input.

Comment: @Michael C. i have updated my answer see is it working as you wanted ?